# Retina Logo is switching sizes and disappears sometimes

Tags: magento-1.9

when visiting [www.juwelier-leopold.de](http://www.juwelier-leopold.de) with a retina screen our logo keeps switching sizes. First you'll see a double size low-res logo, then it switches to the right size after a couple of seconds and sometimes it completely disappears.

Answer (score 0):

if your want to remove Dynamic media query to display @2x images

Remove **data-retina = 'true'** from your **header.phtml** ..

```
public_html/app/design/frontend/default/your-theme-name/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

find code something like that..

```
 <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img data-retina="true" src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
```

clear image cache.